# How to enumerate all the virtual desktops in Windows

Tags: windows-virtual-desktop

I have tried the interface [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager). But it doesn't have any method that will let me get names and ids of all available virtual desktops in Windows. Is this possible?